# C# - CheatSheet for Collection and Generics

Tags: .net, collections

Any cheatsheet available for Collection and Generics in C# 3.0 or 3.5 ?

Comment: It is .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5.  Somewhat confusingly, the c# language and compiler is versioned independently from the .NET Framework. C# 1.0 came with .NET 1.0 and 1.1.  C# 2.0 came with .NET 2.0, and C# 2.0 was the version used with .NET 3.0.  C# 3.0 shipped with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a C# Refcardz by Jon Skeet that might be helpful.

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/csharp

Comment: That site is impressively interested in your address and company information. Presumably that information pays for the hosting and such, but I think I'd prefer it if they don't know where I live, and my phone number. Of course, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Not a cheat cheatsheet [but a fair collection of links](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=48031) in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Scan down 20% on [jeremy's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeremykuhne/archive/2005/07/22/441676.aspx) for a nice succint table summarizing the classes and interfaces.